# Double slash in Cmake add_custom_command causes "No rule to make" error

Tags: makefile, cmake

The following doesn't compile for me using CMake 2.8.3. NOte the "//" caused by a trailing slash on the "DIR" variable. It does compile if that trailing slash is removed.

Anyone know if this is this a bug in CMake or Make, or just user error?

Thanks.

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
    SET(DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/)
    FILE(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${DIR})

    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
            OUTPUT ${DIR}/test.cc
            COMMAND echo "int main(void) { }" > ${DIR}/test.cc
            VERBATIM
    )

    ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${DIR}/test.cc)
```

**Console:**

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sam/tmp
Scanning dependencies of target test
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `test.cc', needed by `CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with this code:

1. You are using shell redirection (`>`) in `add_custom_command` but you have specified the `VERBATIM` flag which doesn't process via the shell.
2. You are not enclosing your paths in quotes, which will cause problems if they contain spaces, `set(DIR ...` should be: `set(DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/")`
3. You are creating files within the source tree; CMake is usually used with out of source builds so temporary files should be created in the build tree
4. You could use `file(WRITE` to create the file, which will be faster than calling out to the shell
5. `cmake_minimum_required` is missing

Fixed `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${DIR}")
file(WRITE "${DIR}/test.cc" "int main(void) {}")

add_executable(test "${DIR}/test.cc")
```